# Returning a set of array to the main method using for loop, gives error deadcode

Tags: java, eclipse

Currently programming a Clock with an alarm and met my first Dead Code error.

---

User input have already stored data into the following variables; aAlarm, aHour, and aMinute.. but I can't seem to get them to display into the main method. I have tried searching other problems regarding dead error and none seem to solve my problem. Below is the code, the variable 'instances' equals to 1 and will increment for the amount of times the user creates an alarm.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Frontend {
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Backend nyet = new Backend();
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int dec, dec2;
        System.out.print("The time is: ");
        System.out.println(nyet.displayClock());
                        //Class clock----------------------------
        
                        //Class setTime--------------------------
        System.out.print("Do you wish to alter time| 1 = Yes, 0 = No:");
        dec = scn.nextInt();
        if (dec == 1) {
            System.out.print("Input Hour:");
            int hour = scn.nextInt();
            if (hour < 0 || hour > 24) {
                System.out.println("Sorry, there are only 24hrs in one day.");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            System.out.print("Input Minute:");
            int minute = scn.nextInt();
            if (minute < 0 || minute > 60) {
                System.out.println("Sorry, there are only 60mins in one hour.");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            System.out.print("Input Second:");
            int second = scn.nextInt();
            if (second < 0 || second > 60) {
                System.out.println("Sorry, there are only 60second in one minute.");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            nyet.setTime(hour, minute, second); 
            scn.close();
            System.out.print("The time is: ");
            System.out.println(nyet.displayClock());
        }               //Class setTime--------------------------
        
                        //Class setAlarm-------------------------
        System.out.print("Do you wish to set an alarm| 1 = Yes, 0 = No:");
        int dec1 = scn.nextInt();
        if (dec1 == 1) {
            do {
                int instc = 1;
                System.out.print("Input alarm number:");
                int aNum = scn.nextInt();
                System.out.print("Input Hour:");
                int aHr = scn.nextInt();
                if (aHr < 0 || aHr > 24) {
                    System.out.println("Sorry, there are only 24hr in one day.");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                System.out.print("Input Minute:");
                int aMin = scn.nextInt();
                if (aMin < 0 || aMin > 60) {
                    System.out.println("Sorry, there are only 60mins in one hour.");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                System.out.print("Do you wish to set another alarm| 1 = Yes, 0 = No:");
                dec2 = scn.nextInt();
                if (dec2 == 1)
                    instc++;
                nyet.setAlarm(instc, aNum, aHr, aMin);
            }while (dec2 != 0);
        }               //Class setAlarm-------------------------
        
        System.out.print("Show alarm| 1 = Show, 0 = Nothing:");
        int z = scn.nextInt();
        if (z == 1)
            nyet.displayAlarm();
    }
}
```

```
import java.time.OffsetTime;

public class Backend {
    
    OffsetTime nyet = OffsetTime.now();
    private int cHour, cMinute, cSecond, instances;
    private int[] aAlarm, aHour, aMinute;
    private boolean[] alarmOn;
    
    public Backend() {
        
        cHour = nyet.getHour();
        cMinute = nyet.getMinute();
        cSecond = nyet.getSecond();

        aHour = new int[2];
        aMinute = new int[2];
        aAlarm = new int[2];
        alarmOn = new boolean[2];

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            alarmOn[i] = !alarmOn[i];
        }
    }

    public void setAlarm(int instncs,int aNmbr, int aHr, int aMnt) {
        for (int i = 0; i < instncs; i++) {
            aAlarm[i] = aNmbr;
            aHour[i] = aHr;
            aMinute[i] = aMnt;
            instances = instncs;
        }
    }
    
    public void setTime(int hr, int min, int sec) {
        cHour = hr;
        cMinute = min;
        cSecond = sec;
    }
    
    public String displayClock() {
        return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", cHour, cMinute, cSecond);
    }
    
    public String displayAlarm() {
        for (int i = 0; i < instances; i++) { //<<< Dead Code
            return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", aAlarm[i], aHour[i], aMinute[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Help us help you - share some sample data and the result you'd like to get for it

Comment: Your `for` loop doesn't make sense. When `instances` is greater than zero, it enters the loop body, and returns immediately with the result of `String::format`. If you want to print something, use `System.out::println`, or concatenate the substring of each iteration into a single string and return that.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. if instances = 1 and i = 0, shouldn't it be true in `i < instances` and then it would run and giving the arrays the index of `i` which is 0 then rerun the for loop?

Comment: At the first iteration, `i = 0` and `instances = 1`, indeed. It enters the loop body and encounters the `return` keyword. The expression behind the `return` keyword is evaluated (the result of `String::format`) **and then it returns immediately from the method**. There is no second iteration.

Comment: But if it enters the loop and immediately returns the expression, why is there no output? I'm sorry, i'm new to java and this is just my first encounter to this problem so I hope you can bear with me.

Comment: By the way, I don't know how Eclipse handles it, but my compiler complains about the `displayAlarm()` method having a *missing return statement*. That does not mean that there is no return statement, but it does mean that not all code paths have one. In your case, if `instances` is `0`, it skips the loop body altogether, and then the method ends without a return statement.

Comment: Well, for starters, post your *whole* code. You haven't shown yet where and how `instances` is set.

Comment: I think I got it, i'll show the answer if what I come up with is correct. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I posted the whole code. I'm still trying to get my mind around this error. Trying if I can perform this step by step rather than using `for loop`

Comment: By the way, you should not store the hour, minute and whethter the alarm is on like this. You are better off creating classes which represent alarms. And then you can store your instances in an array or `List`. For example: `class Alarm { private int hour; private int minute; private boolean on; }`.

Comment: Can you try and code that? I don't know if I thoroughly understood what you meant but i'll try coding it separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess the problem was the class had no 'static' in it.

Front end code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        int dec, dec2, amount = 0, deci0;
        Backend nyet = new Backend();
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
```

```
System.out.print("Do you wish to set an alarm| 1 = Yes, 0 = No:");
        int dec1 = scn.nextInt();
        if (dec1 == 1) {
            do {
                System.out.print("Input alarm number(Stored = " + amount + "):");
                int aNum = scn.nextInt();
                System.out.print("Input Hour:");
                int aHr = scn.nextInt();
                if (aHr < 0 || aHr > 24) {
                    System.out.println("Sorry, there are only 24hr in one day.");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                System.out.print("Input Minute:");
                int aMin = scn.nextInt();
                if (aMin < 0 || aMin > 60) {
                    System.out.println("Sorry, there are only 60mins in one hour.");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                nyet.setAlarm(amount, aNum, aHr, aMin);
                System.out.print("Do you wish to set another alarm(max 3)| 1 = Yes, 0 = No:");
                dec2 = scn.nextInt();
                if (dec2 == 1) {
                    amount++;
                }else if (dec2 == 0) {
                    amount++;
                    nyet.setAlarm(amount, aNum, aHr, aMin);
                }else {
                    System.out.println("The only choices are '1' and '0'.");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                if (amount > 3) {
                    System.out.println("You have reached maximum storage.");
                    dec2 = 0;
                }
            }while (dec2 != 0);
        }
```

Back end code:

```
public class Backend {
    
    OffsetTime nyet = OffsetTime.now();
    private int cHour, cMinute, cSecond;
    private static int[] aAlarm, aHour, aMinute;
    private boolean[] alarmOn;
    private static int amnt;
```

```
public void setAlarm(int instncs,int aNmbr, int aHr, int aMnt) {
        int i = instncs;
        aAlarm[i] = aNmbr;
        aHour[i] = aHr;
        aMinute[i] = aMnt;
        amnt = instncs;
    }


public static void displayAlarm() {
        for (int i = 0; i < amnt; i++) {
            System.out.println("Alarm #" + aAlarm[i] + " - " + aHour[i] + ":" + aMinute[i]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When I entered the code for your class `Backend` in my Eclipse, it showed a build error for method `displayAlarm()`, namely...

> This method must return a result of type String

Here is the code for method `displayAlarm()` (exactly as it appears in your question).

```
public String displayAlarm() {
    for (int i = 0; i < instances; i++) { //<<< Dead Code
        return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", aAlarm[i], aHour[i], aMinute[i]);
    }
}
```

It is possible that the `for` loop in the method will **not** be entered and in that case the method does not return anything. So I just added a line to get rid of the build error.

```
public String displayAlarm() {
    for (int i = 0; i < instances; i++) { //<<< Dead Code
        return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", aAlarm[i], aHour[i], aMinute[i]);
    }
    return "";
}
```

After adding the line, I got the *dead code* warning. I admit that it took me a while to discover the reason. Finally it dawned on me. The only thing in the `for` loop body is `return`. Hence there will only ever be precisely one loop iteration, so why increment `i`?